# Limiting length of each word in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to limit the length of each word in a string?

For example:

1. Loop through each word in a string
2. If a word is longer than X amount of characters, display a pop up message and do not submit the form.

Edit: My final code:

```
$("#comment-form").submit(function(event) {
    var str = $("#comment-box").val(), limit = 135;

    var wordList = str.split(' ');

    $(wordList).each(function(i, word) {
        if(word.length > limit) {
            alert("Your comment has a string with more than " + limit + " characters. Please shorten it.");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please post come code?

Comment: I'm asking how to do something that I don't know how to do. There is no code.

Comment: The answer is: Yes, there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "This is the test string that contains some long words";
var wordList = str.split(' ');
var limit = 4;
$(wordList).each(function(i, word){
    if(word.length >= limit){
        alert(word);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function

```
<script>
    var string = "Please be sure question to answer the question";
    function checkWordLength(string)
    {
        var string_array = string.split(" ");
        for(var i=0; i<string_array.length; i++)
        {
            var word = string_array[i];
            var word_length = word.length;
            if(word_length>6) return false;
        }
    }
    checkWordLength(string);
</script>
```

Comment: function name doesn't make since, as you pass a string into it not a word.

Answer (score 1):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AV7g2/)

```
function CheckString(string, character_limit)
{
    var word = /\w+/igm;
    var match;
    while((match = word.exec(string)) !== null) {
        if(match[0].length > character_limit)
        {
            alert(match[0]);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
var character_limit = 5;
var string = 'this is a string of words and stuff even';
CheckString(string, character_limit);
```

This example uses regular expressions when it returns false make sure to either return false from the `onSubmit` method of your `form`.